# I am trying to redirect my site from www to https. I have this code in htaccess file:

Tags: http, web, redirect, https, cpanel

I have this website https://gss2023.iisdindia.in/ which is already redirected from http to https.

However when we try to access the same website with www prefix - it doesn't redirect to https and show error.

I already tried all the options available to update the .htaccess file but nothing seems to be working for this website.

Can you suggest changes in the .htaccess file ?

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?gss2023.iisdindia\.in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.gss2023.iisdindia.in/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cause is a missing redirect from non-SSL to SSL, you'd use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

But as you're saying that it is already redirecting, I suspect the "error" you mention is that the www subdomain is missing from the certificate so that only the non-www spelling has SSL and when you try to open the www-spelling of the domain you get a browser "insecure page" SSL error. For that case it is not an issue with your redirect, but with a missing www subdomain in your certificate. Make sure that your SSL certificate includes both, the www and non-www spelling of the domain name.